# chars to 2´s complement in C

Tags: c, twos-complement

I have two char´s that I want my program to interpert as one 2´s complement value. For example if I have:

```
char i = 0xFF;
char j = 0xF0;

int k = ((i<<8) | j);
```

Then I want C to interpert k as 2´s complement (so -16 in stead of 65520). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to set all the most significant bits, except the lower 16 to 1. Something like this should do it.

```
k |= (-1&~0xFFFF);
```

That said, if your compiler interprets chars as signed (as I think most do) k is already -16.

Furthermore, with signed chars your result will typically be incorrect if *j* has its most significant bit set (as it does in this case). During the evaluation of the expression, *j* is going to be type promoted to a negative number with all the most significant bits set. When such a number is ORed with the rest of the expression, those bits are going to override everything else. It only works in this case because *i* already has all its bits set so it makes no difference either way.

Answer (score 2):

`int` variables, in comparison to `unsigned int` are always interpreted as two's complement. Your value is just not -16 :)

after you run your code, k will be (assuming 32 bit integer width)

```
k == 0x0000FFF0 // k == 65520
```

whereas:

```
-16 == 0xFFFFFFF0
```

what you can do, to overcome this, is setting all bits of `k` to 1 beforehand

```
int k = -1;          // k == 0xFFFFFFFF
k &= ((i << 8) | j); // k == 0xFFFFFFF0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling your code with a compiler that takes an unqualified `char` as `unsigned`. On my system it is taken as `signed` and I do get `-16`. If you really want 2's complement `char`, that is `signed`, then you can write that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        signed char     i = 0xFF, j = 0xF0;

        printf("%d\n", ((i<<8) | j));
        return 0;
}
```

Just for reference, Appendix J.3.4 Implementation-defined behavior Characters

> Which of `signed char` or `unsigned char` has the same range, representation,
>   and behavior as ‘‘plain’’ `char` (6.2.5, 6.3.1.1).

And in J.3.5 Implementation-defined behavior Integers

> Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and magnitude, two’s
>   complement, or ones’ complement, and whether the extraordinary value is a trap
>   representation or an ordinary value (6.2.6.2).

As Maciej correctly points out it should be noted that shifting left of negative values is undefined behavior and thus should be avoided as compilers may assume you will never shift a negative value to the left.

6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators ad 4

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an `unsigned` type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2^E2` , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type **and nonnegative value**, and `E1 × 2^E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: Using signed chars won't actually work in general. I've added a more detailed explanation why in my answer.

Comment: @JamesHolderness You have a point to the intention of question (it doesn't say so). But in the intention indeed `j` should be taken an `unsigned char`.

Comment: My point is that you can replace the assignment of *i* in your example above with any value at all, and the result will still be -16. I don't see how that can be a considered a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general the bit operations in C/C++ on signed values might have undefined result (the specific format of numbers is not specified - specific wording in section about shifts) - for details see C99 standard. While most architectures currently use 2s-complement and most compilers will generate correct code it is unwise to rely on such assumption - [compilers are known to introduce new optimalizations, which break incorrect code](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/918), even if said code have 'trivial' meaning (for human).

```
unsigned char i = 0xFF; // Char might be either signed or unsigned by default
unsigned char j = 0xF0;
uint16_t bit_result = (i << 8) | j; // 0XFFF0
int32_t sign = (bit_result & (1U << 15)) ? -(1U << 15) : 0;
int32_t result = sign + (bit_result & ((1U << 15) - 1));
```

The above code had no jumps after optimization [preventing constant propagation of i and j so it should be nearly as quick as the code below:

```
// WARNING: Undefined behaviour. Might return wrong value (depending on compiler, processor etc.)
unsigned char i = 0xFF;
unsigned char j = 0xF0;
unsigned uint16_t bit_result = (i << 8) | j; // 0xFFF0
int16_t result = bit_result;
```

In unlikely event that this is performance critical code AND the second code is faster you might consider the second one. Other wise I would use the first one as more correct.

Comment: Actually the signed integer representation is _implementation defined_ and your reference is about _undefined behavior_. That makes a big difference. Also most implementations of C choose to take two's complement. But totally portable code should account for one's complement and sign and magnitude too.

Comment: @BryanOlivier: The binary shifts have undefined behaviour if first argument is negative. That's why I chosen word 'may' as it depends on arguments and operation. You are right but difference between implementation-defined and undefined don't have much impact on answer.

Comment: You are indeed right about the shift, that is on oversight on my part. I will correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: @BryanOlivier actually the int??_t types are guaranteed to be twos compliment if they are available I don't have the spec handy so I don't know section and paragraph but it surprised me when I read it so I remember it.